# Illustrator: how to reproduce rotating object effect in array

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

Could be this effect achieved using a menu command in Illustrator or the only way to produce this it's to rotate each element by hand (which I've tried so far)?
[image]

Comment: wow! that makes my brian sting!

Comment: Have you tried the blend tool?

Comment: Can you please show me in a few print screens or a screen capture? I guess that this is the easiest method. I've figured out creating the square shape but I can't fill the inside area properly. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's Neondude's answer w/ screen shots

1. select you object, go to Object->Transform->Transform Each, and move horizontal, in my sample I did 27 pt, then rotate -11.5 and press Copy.

[image]

2. press Ctrl+D 15 times to complete the top row
   [image]
3. select all 16 items and go to Object->Transform->Transform Each, and move Vertical 32.2 pt, then rotate 11.5 and press Copy.

[image]

4. press Ctrl+D 15 times to complete all rows
   [image]
5. select every other row
   [image]
6. go to Object->Transform->Move, and move -4 pts 
   [image]

Comment: Except thet Neondude does not tell to use transform each.

Comment: @CarlosCanto I'll choose your answer because it's the most clear explained and complete solution; I'm sure that will help others as well. Thank you for your time. Kind regards,

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I was wrong with the blend tool.

Another way to do it is:

- Select your vector object
- Right click and choose Transform Each...
- In the open window, go to the Move section and set Horizontal  to a value. *(I chose .5 in in my screenshot below)*
- Under rotate, enter the degree of rotation you want. *(I chose 15 degrees)*
- Hit Copy. The window will close. To repeat the last action you did, hit CTRL+D on Windows or Command+D on a Mac.
- Do that as many times as you want. *(13 times for me)*
- After that, select the entire row and do Transform Each... again.
- This time, swap the values for Horizontal and Vertical.
- Hit copy and then CTRL+D again. *(15 times for me)*

Screenshot below:
[image: Transform Each...H]

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

One way to make multiple rotations is to duplicate

- select the object you want to rotate
- then right-click>transform>rotate
- enter 'angle' and click copy(not ok)
- Then press ctrl+D do the rotation multiple times.

This way you will have many objects rotated in the same place.

for moving the objects:

- select the top object(of those multiple rotated copies)
- right-click>transform>move
- enter horizontal distance and click ok
- Then press ctrl+D to repeat the transformation
- repeat for each copy of the rotated object

Comment: It could be a soulution but the second phase it's not so easy (not so sure that I understand the ctrl+d part).  could you be so kind and expose a screen capture please?

Comment: @user124853 I have edited the steps. I hope it clears up the confusion.

Comment: I already chose the Carlos 's answer but thank you anyway for your time. kind regards,